# Install full version of Unity on Chrome OS using crouton

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, chromebook

I have an Acer Chromebook.
Using crouton, I installed Ubuntu (unity) on it.
I am pretty familiar Ubuntu 12.04.
But the installed one is very minimized package.
My fonts are missing and I manually installed language pack for Korean but still browser can't display Korean characters.

Is there a way to install the whole packages via crouton like when you install Ubuntu 12.04 with the CD?

Or is there a script that installs the missing packages on the bare Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your ubuntu installation you can run the following:
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
this will install an additional 1 GB of packages and make your installation complete.